# How get a list of files in a directory and rename them in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I am having an issue renaming files with a for loop.
At first I was getting an error with the file being open and unable to rename. Now I am getting the following error:

> TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)

Hope you can assist me with my code.

```
import fnmatch
import os


Path  = r'PATH'
file_name =""

for file in os.listdir(Path):
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, '*.txt'):
        with open(file, 'r') as f:
           fline = f.readline()[:1]
           lline = f.readlines()[-1]

           first = fline.replace("/", "#")
           last = lline.replace("/", "#")
        
        file_name = first + "_" +last + ".m12"
               
        os.rename(file, file_name)
```

Here is an example of what I get with just a print file data

```
    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-92-8f2ead3895f4> in <module>()
      8     if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, '*.txt'):
      9         print(file)
---> 10         with open(file, 'r') as f:
     11             fline = f.readline()[:1]
     12             print(fline) 

TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

UPDATE:

Dave suggested to rename file which I did and now the following error appears:

```
PermissionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-8727ecc0f786> in <module>()

 ---> os.rename(file_, file_name)
      (Above file was changed to file_)
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process
```

Comment: the error might be related to the operating system needs to know in what mode to open the file, try `open(file, 'r')`

Comment: I made that change a : here is my following error: TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)

Comment: error on which line number? what is the full error message?

Comment: davedwards   ---> 10         with open(file, 'r') as f:

Comment: I can't reproduce that error on line 10. Please try to create a [mcve]

Comment: Crazy thing is, I have a print file before the "With Open " and it returns all the files in the folder with no problems. However, the With open is causing the issue here. @davedwards

Comment: ah, I think it's because you're using the built-in keyword [`"file"`](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-file-object) object. Try renaming `file` to something else and run it again.

Comment: Latest error with the modificatin you suggested: PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. @davedwards

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make it work.
Here is my solution to my question.
Dave lead me in the right direction with renaming the file names that were looped in the function. After that help, I found that just using the file open rather than the with open would help me so that I could call the close function.

Thanks for the help everyone.

```
import fnmatch
import os


Path  = r'PATH'
file_name =""
nf = ""

for file in os.listdir(Path):
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, '*.txt'):
       f = open(file_, 'r')
       fline = f.readline()[:1]
       lline = f.readlines()[-1]

       first = fline.replace("/", "#")
       last = lline.replace("/", "#")

    fn = first + "_" +last + ".m12"

    f.close()
    os.rename(file_, fn)
```